# How do I sort randomly generated characters alphabetically?

Tags: java, sorting, random, alphabetical

this is what I have so far

```
public class RandomCharacter
{
    public static char getRandomUpperCaseLetter()
    {
        int ascii = (int) (Math.random()*26) + (int) 'A';
        return (char)ascii;
    }
    public static char getRandomDigitCharacter()
    {
        int digit = (int)(Math.random()*10) + (int) '0';
        return (char)digit;
    }

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {

        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
        {
            System.out.print(getRandomUpperCaseLetter());
            if(i%10 == 0) 
                System.out.print("\n"); 
        }

    }
}
```

I have no clue how to specifically order this alphabetically, I have tried for hours but could not find anything for this. Would someone be able to use my code to teach me how this works?

Comment: Try to insert the elements in Array and use the sort() method Arrays.sort(nameArray)

Answer (score 1):

To sort the values, you must first store them in some data structure eg.an array list before sorting them. Then , if you have used a sortable collection such as the array list, you can use the `.sort()` method and the list will be sorted automatically.
eg/ref:
http://beginnersbook.com/2013/12/how-to-sort-arraylist-in-java/

Answer (score 0):

For natural ordering you can just add the generated alphabets in string and call Collections.sort(listVariable) . This should answer your question.

Sample program

```
import java.util.*;
public class Details  {

public static void main(String args[]){
   ArrayList<String> listofcountries = new ArrayList<String>();
   listofcountries.add("India");
   listofcountries.add("US");
   listofcountries.add("China");
   listofcountries.add("Denmark");

   /*Unsorted List*/
   System.out.println("Before Sorting:");
   for(String counter: listofcountries){
        System.out.println(counter);
    }

   /* Sort statement*/
   Collections.sort(listofcountries);

   /* Sorted List*/
   System.out.println("After Sorting:");
   for(String counter: listofcountries){
        System.out.println(counter);
    }
}
```

}